# Ошибка при создании временной таблицы "ORA-32462: cannot use an object modified in current transaction"

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle18c

Делаю одну вставку в таблицу `temp1`. Сразу после вставки вызываю процедуру, в которой создаю PTT (приватную временную таблицу - *private temporary table*).

При создании используeтся таблицa `temp1`, вот так:

```sql
insert into temp1(name, dept, date) values ('A','HR',sysdate);

create private temporary table ora$ptt_1 as
    select * from temp2 where dept ='HR' and name ='A';
```

Но получаю ошибку:

> ORA-32462: cannot use an object modified in current transaction

Что делаю не так, как обойти ошибку?

<sub>Свободный перевод [ORA-32462: cannot use an object modified in current transaction](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60933678/6571020) от участника [@ManojSrivastava](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8471950/manoj-srivastava)</sub>

Comment: ассоциация:https://stackoverflow.com/q/60933678/6571020

Answer (score 3):

Нельзя использовать таблицу для создания PTT, которая была изменена в текушей транзакции.

Так как, время жизни PTT по умолчанию транзакция, то в данном случае есть исключение из правила: перед выполнением `CREATE PRIVATE TEMPORARY ...` не будет произведён неявный `COMMIT`, что обычно имеет место для всех DDL.

Поэтому, как и предлагается в описании ошибки:

> 32462, 0000, "cannot use an object modified in current transaction"
>   // *Cause:  An object modified in the current transaction was found during the creation of
>   //          in-memory private temporary table using CREATE TABLE AS SELECT (CTAS).
>   // *Action: **Split the CTAS statement into CREATE TABLE followed by INSERT SELECT**.

Сначала создайте PTT таблицу, затем заполните её отдельной вставкой:

```sql
create table temp1 (name varchar2 (32), dept varchar2 (4), hired date);
insert into temp1 values ('A', 'HR', sysdate);

create private temporary table ora$ptt_1 as
    select * from temp1 where dept ='HR' and name ='A';

Error report -
ORA-32462: cannot use an object modified in current transaction

create private temporary table ora$ptt_1 (name varchar2 (32), dept varchar2 (4), hired date);

Private TEMPORARY created.

insert into ora$ptt_1 
    select * from temp1 where dept ='HR' and name ='A';

1 row inserted.
```